# Can html element be skipped by css?

Tags: html, css

### TL;DR:

Is it possible for css to ignore html element, but not its children?
Such element would be treated by css as if it wasn't there; but its children would be treated normally, i.e. as children of parent of the ignored element.

### Details, Motivation:

Let's say we have a nice styled layout, e.g. with `display: flex`.

```html
<div className="outer"><!-- this one has display: flex (just example) -->
  <div className="inner">Foo</div>
  <div className="inner">Bar</div>
  <div className="inner">Baz</div>

  <div className="inner">Foo 2</div>
  <div className="inner">Bar 2</div>
  <div className="inner">Baz 2</div>
</div>
```

But then, we need to wrap one group of our `inner` elements into `form`, or `nav` (for semantic or other reasons):

```html
<div className="outer">
  <div className="inner">Foo</div>
  <div className="inner">Bar</div>
  <div className="inner">Baz</div>

  <form>
    <div className="inner">Foo 2</div>
    <div className="inner">Bar 2</div>
    <div className="inner">Baz 2</div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Well, of course this breaks our desired layout (e.g. `flex`), because `<form>` became the child of `outer`, and sibling of the first three `inner`s.

**Is it possible to make an element, in this case `form`, to be ignored by css - as if it wasn't there in the html element tree?**

**If it's not possible, has this feature ever been considered, worked on, rejected... ?**

Comment: It's possible using [CSS sub-grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Subgrid). Doesn't look like something similar exists for flex though.

Comment: @connexo Cool. Well, it would indeed be nice to at least have a flex-specific solution. But i'm looking for a more general "css skipping". I don't see a theoretical reason why it couldn't be a thing. So i'm curious, is it a thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's exactly what [display:contents](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display#contents) is designed to do. So:

```
form { display:contents }
```

```css
.outer { 
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

form { 
  display: contents;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">Foo</div>
  <div class="inner">Bar</div>
  <div class="inner">Baz</div>

  <form>
    <div class="inner">Foo 2</div>
    <div class="inner">Bar 2</div>
    <div class="inner">Baz 2</div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Keep in mind that currently, [browsers have a bug](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display#display_contents), which makes our `form` element inaccessible to screen readers. That's problematic for semantic/logical elements from accessibility POV. Hopefully this will be fixed in the future.

Answer (score 0):

just set the form to `display: flex`

now the form is a direct child... so you can for example set it to `flex:1` or so.
and you will get a new "parent" for the form child elements.